# CSS: how to make bottom div width same as the width of image above?

Tags: css, dynamic, alignment

http://www.kuwaitjournals.org/test

How can I  fix the width of the main `<div>` with the image on top, or make the width of the top image dynamic like the main `<div>`?

Comment: please elaborate more of what you want to achieve. Write some code so we can understand what are you trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I'd say you just have to use percentages as width. Something like this as HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="foo/bar.jpg" />
            <div id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this for CSS:

```
*, html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

img {
    width: 100%; //Sets the image width to 900px
}

#content {
    width: 100%; //Sets the content divs width to 900px
}
```

This is an answer to what I think the question is. If it's not, please do tell me.